# Difficulty Converting url in linux in htaccess file

Tags: .htaccess, codeigniter, url-rewriting

I am developing a website in linux in codeigniter

I have the below url

```
  http://www.abc.com/wes/?mlevel=2&level=2&name=wii%20pro&code=22
```

and would like it to be like this for the user top type in the url

```
http://www.abc.com/wes_wii+pro-22.html
```

how can I achieve this I have not been successfull with what I have tried

Comment: mlevel and level are not same

Comment: Do you have `wes` controller ? And i dont see `mlevel` and `level` on this url `http://www.abc.com/wes_wii+pro-22.htm`

Comment: Yes I have wes controller and mlevel and level are needed to use $_GET

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I'm not sure which fields you meant to capture there, but it would be something like:

```
order allow,deny
allow from all

RewriteEngine On
RewriteBase /


RewriteRule ^wes_(.*)-(.*)$ /wes/?mlevel=$2&level=$2&name=$1&code=$2
```